# how to give button in status notification bar?

Tags: android, notifications

i am developing an application in android which will notify user his current location...i want to give button as "show map" inside a notification message when on clicked he can view the map

Answer (score 1):

Use RemoteViews to create a custom view for your notification. See Creating a Custom Expanded View section in 
[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)